# New Angular CLI project fails on Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, angular

As of this morning, when I use the Angular CLI to create a new project it throws an exception on IE11 and returns this error message (in the console).

> ```
> SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'call' of undefined or null reference
> File: inline.bundle.js, Line: 55, Column: 12
> ```

Yesterday it worked without error.

I am using

Angular CLI: 1.5.3
Node: 6.9.5
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 5.0.2

These are the steps I follow to create the project

```
ng new tempProject
cd tempProject\
npm install --save classlist.js
npm install --save web-animations-js
```

I then edit the polyfill.ts file and uncomment everything except for 'intl'.   After that I use 'ng serve' and try to load it in IE.  I have even deleted the node_modules directory and used npm install to recreate it.  It works fine on chrome, of course.  But I need to get it working on IE11 because it's the corporate standard where I work.

Every github issue talks about the polyfill file.  But unless I'm supposed to add something to it that I don't know about, that doesn't help me.  Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: so what's around line 55 column 12 of `inline.bundle.js`? also, when you look at the stack trace of the error, does that help you find the cause of the error?

Comment: Can you set up your project on plunker or any other online tool?

Comment: Just read the comments inside the file "src/polyfills.ts" in your project. You will get clear idea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turned out that this was just Internet Explorer forgetting how to run javascript or something.  Once I shut down IE, waited for it to really close (watch task manager to see for sure), and then started it up again it worked fine.

Comment: Yep. It had me so confused, because it happened right after I had changed a random line of text and I was trying to figure out how the hell that had broken something.

Answer (score 2):

Please check your polyfills.js file and uncomment below lines of code and then try again.

And also update target in tsconfig.json : `"target": "es5"`,

```
/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';

/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for NgClass support on SVG elements */
// import 'classlist.js';  // Run `npm install --save classlist.js`.

/** Evergreen browsers require these. **/
import 'core-js/es6/reflect';
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';
```